# Is it good style to embed Design Pattern names into Interface names?

Tags: design-patterns, coding-style

Would it be good practice/style to embed design pattern names into appropriate interface lets say if its a decorator design pattern have the abstract decorator be named `IDecorateInterfaceName` or `AbstractClassNameDecorator` if abstract class is used for the pattern. As example java I/O classes use decorator pattern but name the Abstract Decorator class just `FilterInputStream` instead of adding the pattern name somewhere in the name. Or does it become redundant to add this type of information if sufficient documentation is provided? It just seemed to me that it would be easier to catch on which patterns are used just by looking at code if this convention is followed throughout but the fact that APIs didn't follow such a rule is throwing me off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately language designers offer us some insight in this

- [Java naming guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html)
- [C# Naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28VS.71%29.aspx)

When naming your classes, methods, and variables - your #1 goal should always be to improve readability (and thus convey to readers of your code what things are actually doing).  In your example of the decorator pattern, it is not relevant to include 'AbstractDecorator' in the name of the class because that doesn't tell anyone what the object *actually does*.

It is really a case by case basis thing though - for example in many MVC frameworks, it is common convention to add a "Controller" suffix to every class that is a Controller (per that design pattern).  In this instance adding a the design pattern to name helps users understand what the object is doing.

When in doubt, just ask yourself the question "Will this make my code easier read and understand?"

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, knowing which pattern is used isn't what matters. What matters is what the class is and does. FilterInputStream says that clearly. The fact that it implements the decorator pattern is an implementation details, that is easily recognized if you know the pattern, and that doesn't add much information if you don't know it.

That said, some pattern names clearly describe what a class is, like factory or strategy, so they're often used as part of the class name. For example, a SecretKeyFactory is a factory for secret keys, and implements the factory pattern. But I would hate to have classes named like RuntimeSingleton or FileFilterStrategy. These suffixes are noise.

BTW, I also hate this `I` prefix convention of C# for interfaces. It's the same kind of noise that makes code less readable and doesn't add meaningful information.

Comment: I like the `I` prefix about as much as I like classes beginning with a capital letter (that is to say, a lot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface if you wish to expose your decorator to another application, for example your development based on WCF architecture n tiers must be implement interface.

Answer (score 0):

In "Use Solution Domain Names" section of "Meaningful Names" Chapter 2 of book "Clean Code", Robert Martin says:

> Remember that the people who read your code will be programmers. So go
>   ahead and use computer science (CS) terms, algorithm names, pattern
>   names, math terms, and so forth.
>
> The name "AccountVisitor" means a great deal to a programmer who is
>   familiar with the VISITOR pattern. What programmer would not know what
>   a "JobQueue" was? There are lots of very technical things that
>   programmers have to do. Choosing technical names for those things is
>   usually the most appropriate course.